# Unable to remove a user from Administrators group (win 10)

Tags: windows-10

I get an error any time I try removing a user from Administrators group. Moreover, when I try deleting it, I get error "Cannot delete account because it is predefined"

What does 'predefined' mean exactly?

Any hints on how to overcome this?

Comment: What is the name of the username. It’s not possible to delete the built-in Administrator account

Comment: The name actually is cBianchi, was used by a standard employee

Comment: Are we sure it’s not the built-in Administrator account simply renamed?

Comment: Might have been that once. In such case it cannot be altered, right?

Comment: You can alter it you just can't deleted it. For instance you could rename it back, disable it, change the password. As it is actually reinstalling Windows on that particular machine might be a good idea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a bunch of predefined users in Windows, which always exist and can't be deleted.

Run the following in a PowerShell session:

(Get-LocalUser -Name cBianchi).Sid.Value

look at the very end of the output after the last dash, if it is a number less than 1000, the account is a built-in account that was renamed.

For example a `-500` is the local administrator account on every Windows machine.

Just disable the account if you can't delete it.